# How can I share my wifi Internet connection from Android phone to a Linux Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, usb, tethering

How can I share my wifi Internet connection from an Android phone to a Linux Raspberry Pi?

I am trying to share my Wifi connection from the phone to a Raspberry Pi 3B. USB tethering is connected. I can access the RPi3 from the phone over SSH. But when I try to ping some website or browse I get the error message from Terminal:

Network is unreachable.

Any advice?

Vesa

Comment: Does your carrier allow tethering? Some carriers/operators only allow tethering on select plans (usually the most expensive ones). Tethering detection typically involves checking the value in the TTL (Time to Live) field of the packets sent out by your phone.

Comment: I have no carrier on this phone. But I couldn't get the setup to work on the other phone either. Both phones are unlocked and "unblocked". Please note I'm not trying to share 4G to USB tethering but wifi from public wifi to USB tethering.